# regarding explanation of statement System.out.println();

Tags: java, system.out

i want to know  what each term in `System.out.println()` means?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java beginner question: System.out.println](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999661/java-beginner-question-system-out-println)

Answer (score 2):

- [`System`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) is a class name, you access the *class* (not an instance of
  it) with `System.*`
- `out` is a *class variable* in that class of type [`PrintStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html)
- [`println()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28%29) is a method in `PrintStream`

Comment: is " out " a static variable?

Comment: @Surya: Yes, a *class variable* is a static variable.